# What does it mean when a question is greyed out?

Tags: support

When I visit avp.stackexchange.com I see [this question regarding LiVES software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/software-like-lives-video-editing-for-windows-7) in the active list. However it is greyed out as shown in this image:

[image]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it means it has a tag in your ignored tags list.  I can make a question in the feed look like that if I add it's tag to ignored.

Comment: I accidentally set the `audio-recording` tag to ignored. Thanks for the help.